# Change HTML language from en-US in to en-UK in WordPress?

Tags: html, wordpress, lang

How can i change HTML lang from en-us to en-uk, i have selected en-uk in wordpress dashboard but its displaying en-gb `<html lang="en-GB">`.

Simply i want to change
`<html lang="en-US">`
to:
`<html lang="en-UK">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the wp-config.php put the following line:

```
$locale = 'en-UK';
```

Answer (score 1):

try to copy and paste this php function in your functions.php file:

```
function wp_change_lang_attribute( $lang ) {
return 'en-UK';
}
add_filter( 'language_attributes', 'wp_change_lang_attribute' );
```